# Magento 2 How can i remove coupon code from checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, discount

I'd like to remove coupon code from the last step of the checkout "Payment and Review".

I have a custom theme with checkout_index_index.xml in Magento_Checkout/layout folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply adding following tag

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

So **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml** looks like

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no <item name="discount" xsi:type="array"> code in my file.

Comment: You can found this tag 'Magento/SalesRule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml' here.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the **Apply Coupon Code** Field at the checkout in
**Magento 2.3** add:

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

in the checkout_index_index.xml file

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

under the discount item

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
```

so it looks like

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

have fun!